# Xalanc Transformation Error: Could not determine base pathname of the file (, line 0, column 0)

Tags: c++, parsing, xslt, aix, xalan

I've been kind of thrown into trying to figure out why this is failing in AIX. We make the following calls:

```
void
SAXParser::TransformFile()
{
    if(!mbPerformTransformation)
        return;

    XalanTransformer theXalanTransformer;

    // The assumption is that the executable will be run
    // from same directory as the input files.
    int theResult = theXalanTransformer.transform(mpcFileName, GetXSLTTransformationFileName(), TRANSFORMED_FILE_NAME);

    if(theResult != 0)
    {
        throw MyException( string("Xalanc Transformation Error: \n") + string(theXalanTransformer.getLastError()) );
    }
}
```

When I get in here, I can view the `mpcFileName` just fine as `file.xml`, however I'm getting the following error output when I attempt to call `transform()` on it:

```
XSLT Warning: Fatal Error.Occurred at unknown file, line 0, column 0. An exception occurred! Type:XMLPlatformException, Message:Could not determine base pathname of the file (line -1, column -1.)
```

and ultimately...

```
Xalanc Transformation Error: 
SAXParseException: An exception occurred! Type:XMLPlatformException, Message:Could not determine base pathname of the file (, line 0, column 0)
```

I have no clue what I'm doing... I can't debug the `transform()` method, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the file name look like? Where is that file actually located? What's the current directory when you execute the code?

Comment: current directory is where the exe is - text file is in the format `ABC-MyFile.xml`

Comment: Is that file also in the directory with the .exe? Are you sure the name you have given is correct -- remember that AIX filenames are case-sensitive...

Comment: Yes, the file is also in that directory (though, I'm not sure that it matters because even though we have the comment to expect the file in the cwd, I can see the path/file.txt has been appended by our framework in that case). Names are exact.

Comment: try calling it with a relative path (to the current directory), AND quoting to avoid any issues with the `-` char in your filename, i.e. `xslt_cmd './ABC-MyFile.xml'` or to eimininate any ambiguity about the files location, use the file path, ie. `... '/path/to/my/troublesome/ABC-MyFile.xml'`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here did in fact turn out to be path related - I was just looking at the *wrong* path. The required files (param 2 and 3) were missing from the directory.